# Delete entry from laravel.log

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I am building application on laravel. Now application itself should PCI DSS compliant. Hence we can't store card details on file.Now we don't store details anywhere itself.But when request hits at server.Then laravel logs that information into laravel.log.

Is there a programmable way so that we could remove that entry from laravel.log?

Comment: Debug your code and remove line that stores data in `laravel.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `laravel.log` on production logs errors not request details.

Unless somewhere you have a call intentionally logging requests into that file via middleware or a method in a class or trait.

Answer (score 0):

> when request hits at server.Then laravel logs that information into
>   laravel.log.

Laravel does not log any information until we ask to store any data.

if you still confuse and you don't want to log anything u can set it in application settings.

in your `.env`

change this

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

to this

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=null
```